# NativeScript - When I am trying to take a build in Android I am getting an Error as below but I can able to take build in IOS

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

NativeScript - When I am trying to take a build in Android I am getting an Error as below but I can able to take build in IOS.

ERROR in ../node_modules/nativescript-permissions/permissions.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@master.technology/permissions' in
'/node_modules/nativescript-permissions'
@ ../node_modules/nativescript-permissions/permissions.js 13:17-58
@ ../node_modules/nativescript-camera/camera.js
@ ./app/virtualevent/virtualevent.component.ts
@ ./app/app.module.tns.ts
@ ./main.tns.ts
Webpack compilation complete.
Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.

The above is the error we are getting when trying to take the Android Build

Environment:
OS: macOS 12.3
CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
Shell: /bin/zsh
node: 14.18.2
npm: 6.14.15
nativescript: 8.1.5

## android

java: 17.0.2
ndk: Not Found
apis: Not Found
build_tools: Not Found
system_images: Not Found

## ios

xcode: 13.3/13E113
cocoapods: 1.11.2
python: Not Found
python3: 3.8.9
ruby: 2.7.5
platforms:

- DriverKit 21.4
- iOS 15.4
- macOS 12.3
- tvOS 15.4
- watchOS 8.5

Dependencies:

"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^12.2.5",
"@angular/common": "^12.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "^12.2.5",
"@angular/core": "^12.2.5",
"@angular/forms": "^12.2.5",
"@angular/http": "~8.0.0-beta.10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.5",
"@angular/router": "^12.2.5",
"@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.1",
"@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^1.0.0",
"base-64": "^1.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.6.9",
"material-ui-search-bar": "^0.4.2",
"nativescript-accordion": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
"nativescript-app-tour-updated": "^2.0.2",
"nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
"nativescript-collectionview": "^2.0.36",
"nativescript-danem-drop-down": "^1.0.3",
"nativescript-datetimepicker": "^1.2.2",
"nativescript-email": "^1.6.0",
"nativescript-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.0.3",
"nativescript-imagecropper": "^4.0.0",
"nativescript-imagepicker": "^7.1.0",
"nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
"nativescript-oauth": "^2.1.8",
"nativescript-oauth2": "^2.4.0",
"nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.9",
"nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.5.2",
"nativescript-slides": "^2.3.0",
"nativescript-ui-autocomplete": "^6.0.1",
"nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^8.0.1",
"nativescript-websockets": "^1.5.6",
"pusher-nativescript": "^1.0.0",
"reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
"rxjs": "~7.3.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
"tslib": "1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4",
"@nativescript/core": "~8.1.1",
"@nativescript/angular": "^12.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.5",
"@angular/cli": "^12.2.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.5",
"@nativescript/android": "~8.1.1",
"@nativescript/ios": "~8.1.0",
"@nativescript/schematics": "~1.0.0",
"@nativescript/tslint-rules": "~0.0.5",
"@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
"@ngtools/webpack": "^13.2.5",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^5.2.3",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"protractor": "^7.0.0",
"sass": "~1.39.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.15.0",
"typescript": "~4.3.5"
}

Comment: Did you find a solution?